# Convert Certain Characters to HTML Link

Tags: php, special-characters

I have a string like this

```
"hello my #old good #friends"
```

I want certain words such as (#example) to be converted to HTML links

```
"hello my <a href='example.com/tags/old'>old</a> good <a href='example.com/tags/friends'>friends</a>"
```

Thanks

sorry for my english

Comment: So you want to convert each # to the URL?

Comment: I think the question is clear, after each `#` there is a word, use that to make the link.

Comment: Using `php` or `jquery`?

Comment: thanks guys . I got my answer .

Comment: @AmirGheybi its ok. cool :)) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using php you can do like below (easiest and fast):-

use `preg_replace()`:-

```
<?php
   $data = "hello my #old good #friends";
   $patterns = array ('/#(.*?)\s/','/#(.*)$/'); // first one is start with # end with space   and second is start with # till the end
   $replace = array("<a href='example.com/tags/$1'>$1</a> ","<a href='example.com/tags/$1'>$1</a>");
   echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $data);
?>
```

output:- https://eval.in/595251

Using `jquery`

you have lot of answer given with working example. Check them.

Comment: Great Answer . thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP without Regular expression

```
    $string = "hello my #old good #friends";
    $new_string=[];
    $new_string = explode(' ', $string);

    foreach ($new_string as $key => $value) {
        $space = 0 === $key ? '' : ' ';
        if ('#' === $value[0]) {
            $n_str=  str_replace("#", '', $value);
            echo "$space<a href='example.com/tags/$n_str'>$n_str</a> ";
        } else {
            echo $space . '' . $value;
        }
    }
```

html Output

```
hello my <a href='example.com/tags/old'>old</a> good <a href='example.com/tags/friends'>friends</a>
```

Comment: Thanks . Worked Great !

Answer (score 0):

Using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in PHP you could do this:

```
$someText = "hello #old things";

//Returns an array of hashtags
preg_match("/#(\w+)/", $someText, $matches);

//Generate an array of links from the hashtags
$links = [];
foreach ($matches as $hashtag)
{
    $link = "<a href=\"site.com/tag/{$hashtag}\">{$hashtag}</a>";
    array_push($links, $link);
}

//replace the arrary of hashtags in our string with the link
$string = str_replace($matches, $links, $someText);
```

Now there's probably a way to do a string replace inside, but this is all that immediately came to mind. I'll look into the string replace though and edit with my findings.

Edit: Do you want to do this in php or js?

Answer (score 0):

> Split the string, change through it and add again.

```
var converted = str.split(' ').map(function(st){
    if(st.indexOf('#') !== -1){
        st = '<a href="example.com/tags/' + st.replace('#', '') + '">' + st.replace('#', '') + '</a>';
    }
    return st;
});
converted.join(' ');
```

```js
var str = "hello my #old good #friends";
$('#change').on('click', function() {
  var converted = str.split(' ').map(function(st) {
    if (st.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
      st = '<a href="example.com/tags/' + st.replace('#', '') + '">' + st.replace('#', '') + '</a>';
    }
    return st;
  });
  $('#test').html(converted.join(' '));
})



//"hello my <a href='example.com/tags/old'>old</a> good <a href='example.com/tags/friends'>friends</a>"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  "hello my #old good #friends"
</div>
<button id="change">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally whipping up a quick answer, which may be overdone a bit or not the most clever way... but here goes:

```
<?php

//
$string1="hey #bro this is #such a cool #answer";
$string2="hey bro this is such a cool answer";

//
print "\n String1 == ".LinkifyHashtags($string1);
print "\n String2 == ".LinkifyHashtags($string2);

//
function LinkifyHashtags($string)
{
    //
    $matches=true;

    //
    $string_linkified=$string;

    //  Grab all hashtags
    if(Preg_Match_All('@\#(?P<hash_word>\w+)@',$string,$matches)){

        //  Iterate over all matches
        foreach($matches['hash_word'] as $word){
            $word_ent=HtmlEntities($word,ENT_COMPAT,'utf-8');
            $word_enc=UrlEncode($word);
            $string_linkified=Str_Replace("#{$word}","<a href=\"/tags/{$word_enc}\">{$word_ent}</a>",$string_linkified);
        }
    }

    return $string_linkified;
}

?>
```

Comment: Huh we both came up with similar answers but slightly different execution! I choose to do one string replace after creating an array of hashtags, you choose to do the string replace at the same time. Although I'll give you points for creating a function for it!

Comment: @XanderLuciano lol nice. Yours is better if we assume Str_Replace() is optimized when using arrays as opposed to just repeated calls.

Comment: omg... I fumbled the word_ent / word_enc logic ... fixing

Comment: Haha I always feel like it's a rush to see who can type up the best working code example first for these things.

Answer (score 0):

> Jquery Version:

```
$(function(){
   var test = 'hello my #old good #friends';
   test = test.split(' ');
   test = test.map(function(item){
      return item.indexOf('#') > -1?"<a href='example.com/tags/"+item.slice(1)+"'>"+item.slice(1)+"</a>":item;
   });
   $('#divResult').html(test.join(' '));
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q62htLf9/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var words = 'hello my #old good #friends';
var wordarr = words.split(' ');
var str = '';
$.each(wordarr,function(i,val){
    if(wordarr[i].indexOf('#') == 0){

        wordarr[i] = '<a href="example.com/tags/'+wordarr[i].replace("#", "")+'">'+wordarr[i].replace("#", "")+'</a>';
      str += wordarr[i]+' ';  
    }else{
        str += wordarr[i]+' ';  
    }

});
$('#result').html(str);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t8o67xuk/1/